# how to download zip file from required certificate https url in C# or SSIS?

Tags: c#, https, ssis

I have an HTTPS URL to download a zip file but I need to install certificate from site. I installed it already on my machine.

Here is my code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //RemoteCertificateValidationCallback ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFile("https://markets.midwestiso.org/MISO/getSettlementStatementFile?entity=CORP_SUB3&nodeId=key0", @"C:\files\1.zip");
        }
```

But I'm getting the below error message:

> **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

Please help. I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: just try url on the matching https://markets.midwestiso.org/MISO/getSettlementStatementFile/1.zip?entity=CORP_SUB3&nodeId=key0  i think some issue with url

Comment: @sandeeprawat you need install certificate on machine than you can access url.

Comment: @Meghan Armes Thank you for edits.